# Oozie - EL_ERROR: cannot convert String to type Double

Tags: el, oozie, oozie-workflow

Getting oozie EL_ERROR. Please find below the oozie workflow details. Please advise.

Error Code: EL_ERROR
**Error Message**: An exception occured trying to convert String "/tmp/dir" to type "java.lang.Double"

**Expected Result:** /tmp/dir/0007735-200221155317872-oozie-oozi-W/destination

*workflow.xml*

```
<decision name="On_Success">
    <switch>
       <case to="success">${fs:dirSize(hdfs_path_variable+wf:id()+hdfs_dir) gt 0 }</case>
       <default to="fail"/>
    </switch>
</decision>
```

*job.properties*

```
hdfs_path_variable=/tmp/dir
hdfs_dir=destination
```

Comment: You assume that Java EL uses **operator `+`** for **String concatenation**. You are wrong. Java EL has _arithmetic_ operators. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html

Comment: Now, a simple Google query about `java expression language string concatenation oozie` will return some useful links such as https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/String-concatenation-in-Oozie-expression-language/td-p/144497 or even, OMG, the actual Oozie documentation!!! https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.2_Basic_EL_Functions

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802657/oozie-el-function-an-exception-occured-trying-to-convert-string-to-type-java-l